# JDBC connecting to MySQL keeps telling me I am breaking foreign key constraint? Wha?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Okay, so I keep getting this error:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

And it's really frustrating and I don't know why?  All I did was assign a foreign key to a primary key in another table (the books table to be precise).  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
        //create patron table
        s.executeUpdate ("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS patron");
        s.executeUpdate (
            "CREATE TABLE patron ("
            + "patron_ID CHAR(10),"
            + "PRIMARY KEY (patron_ID),"
            + "fName CHAR(50)NOT NULL, MI CHAR(2), lName CHAR(75)NOT NULL,"
            + "street_Name CHAR(100)NOT NULL, city CHAR(50) NOT NULL, state CHAR(50)NOT NULL,"
            + "zip_Code CHAR(10) NOT NULL, home_Phone CHAR(12)NOT NULL, call_Number CHAR(10)NOT NULL,"
            //+ "FOREIGN KEY (call_Number) references corejava.book(call_Number))");
            + "FOREIGN KEY (call_Number) references " + dbName + ".book (call_Number))");

        count2 = s.executeUpdate (
            "INSERT INTO patron"
            + " VALUES"
            + "('P222200000', 'Harry', 'P','Bradford','1234 Street Place','Silver Spring','Maryland','20906','301-555-9999','MY.111.0001'),"
            + "('P222200001', 'Sally','','Titus','2365 Huckleberry Lane','Silver Spring','Maryland','20906','301-554-9896','SF.111.002'),"
            + "('P222200002', 'Mark', 'C','Bradley','654 Finance Lane','Silver Spring','Maryland','20906','301-665-4978','AV.111.004'),"
            + "('P222200003', 'Carlos','','Iglesias','987 Potter Place','Silver Spring','Maryland','20906','240-702-5648','CO.111.006'),"
            + "('P222200004', 'Chris','','Craig','951 Einstein Way','Silver Spring','Maryland','20906','301-569-4415','IN.111.008'),"
            + "('P222200005', 'Samantha','A','Brikmon',' 8380 Colesville Road','Silver Spring','20906','301-659-5569','CO.111.007'),"
            + "('P222200006', 'Lindsey', '','Saucer','12507 Winexburg Manor Drive','Silver Spring','Maryland','20906','301-632-6635','SF.111.003'),"
            + "('P222200007', 'Judy', 'A','Freud','2518 Woodedge Road','Glenmont','Maryland','20905','240-985-9632','AV.111.005'),"
            + "('P222200008', 'Elizabeth','M','Longhorn','552 Lockwood Drive','Wheaton','Maryland','20904','202-555-6639','IN.111.009'),"
            + "('P222200009', 'Gabriella', 'S','Young','654 Glenallen Road','Silver Spring','Maryland','20906','301-555-9898','MY.111.000')");

        System.out.println (count2 + " rows were inserted");
        s.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to insert a record in `patron` that has a `call_Number` that does not exist in any row of table `book`.

Answer (score 2):

What it means is that in your insertions to the patron table, in the last column (e.g. first record has `'MY.111.0001'`), there are some values that do not exist in `book.call_number`.  That is the purpose of foreign keys, to make sure data is consistently referenced!  Allowing the insert would leave some value of `patron.call_number` to be invalid.

Comment: Wooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooow.  I am sooooooooooo smart. I think I have been staring at this screen to long.  time for a break. I already see one point of controversy, the dang value for the 1st foreign key is a character too long!!!  I am so special:)   Tanks mon.

Answer (score 1):

Are the values you are putting into patron.call_number the same as the ones in book.call_number?

Answer (score 1):

Execute:

```
select * from book where call_number = 'MY.111.0001';
```

for each of the call numbers (`MY.111.0001` above but substitute in each in turn) you're trying to insert into `patron` to ensure the row exists.

That should show you which particular record is causing the constraint violation, at which point you either use a different call number or insert a row for that call number into `book`.

Alternatively, you could execute:

```
select call_number from book where call_number in (
    'MY.111.0001',
    'SF.111.002',
    'AV.111.004',
    'CO.111.006',
    'IN.111.008',
    'CO.111.007',
    'SF.111.003',
    'AV.111.005',
    'IN.111.009',
    'MY.111.000')
```

and see which of those don't show up in the output.

Looking at the length of that first one once they're nicely lined up, I suspect it's a problem - perhaps it should be `MY.111.001`?